# how to avoid inactive window dimming in KDE?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

I like my windows to get dimmer when inactive (not with focus)

But I'd like to except some, like media players.

i tried to add to `Settings` > `Window Management` > `Window Rules` a rule that matches `Window Role = ExactMatch(vlc-main)`, triggering under `Appearance & fixes` the rule `Block compositing = force, yes`

But it did not work as i expected.

The only other relevant action would be to force inactive opacity to 100%, but I use the default KDE settings and inactive windows are already 100% opacity but dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue but running Manjaro - plasma, i'm making the assumption it will apply.

I found i had 'deactivated': System Settings-> Desktop Effects-> Dim Inactive.  So i assumed it wasn't contributing to my issue of 'over dimmed Konsole windows'.

However on 'activating' and setting strength to 0 and selecting all the options

1. docks and pannels.
2. desktop..
   etc..

fixed the issue!

all the best.
Tristan.